# What is the command to determine if OpenSSL and mod_ssl are installed on apache2?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

Does anyone know the command to determine if OpenSSL and mod_ssl are installed on apache2?

Regards, Fiona

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To check apache modules installed on your system:

```
apache2ctl -M or apachectl -M
```

To check if OpenSSL is installed in your system:

For GNU/Linux distros that use rpm packages:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i openssl
```

For GNU/Linux distros that use deb packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i openssl
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me HD.

To check for OpenSSL, neither command is working. I'm running Ubuntu Hardy. Is there a specific command for this distribution?

Regards,
Fiona

Comment: The dpkg command should work on Hardy, When you say 'not working', does that mean nothing is returned?  In that case, you just don't have the 'openssl' package installed

Comment: As Kyle says if dpkg doesn't return nothing then openssl package is not installed.

Comment: ok.. sorry bout that, a typo..

It looks like OpenSSL is installed:

ii  openssl                           0.9.8g-4ubuntu3.7           Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related
ii  openssl-blacklist                 0.3.3+0.4-0ubuntu0.8.04.3   list of blacklisted OpenSSL RSA keys
ii  ssl-cert                          1.0.14-0ubuntu2.1           Simple debconf wrapper for openssl

Regards,
Fiona

Comment: Or, if you are using `Arch` Linux, then it would be `pacman -Q openssl`

Answer (score 3):

With apache2 in a Debian environment:

```
sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

or

```
sudo apache2ctl -S
```

This will show all the modules that are currently loaded into Apache, you may have other installed, but not loaded.  To find that out the simplest way I know of is to look in the /etc/apache2/mods-available directory.

If it is not loaded, and you think it is installed, you can always use the [load module directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_so.html) to try to load it and see if it errors out (if you can have a little downtime that is)

Comment: -S and -M are just aliases for apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES